# How to set value of Variable<int> which is used in UiPath, using C#

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation, uipath

I am not able to set variable value due to activity context .

`Variable<int> variable = new Variable<int>(); variable.Set(?,23424);` 
In above code Set method wants ActivityContext, unable to create any instance of ActivityContext,
how to set the value for Variable?, Please refer https://github.com/UiPath/CoreWF.